# JMF Error - The method getDeviceList returns a Vector whose size is 0

Tags: java, video, webcam, jmf

I am developing an application that should capture images from a webcam in Java, for that I am using JMF (Java Media Framework). I'm having trouble recognizing the WebCam.

```
Vector devices = CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList (null);
```

The method `getDeviceList` returns a `Vector` whose size is 0. I installed JMStudio and he recognizes my webcam. My project is in Eclipse, I added the jmf's jars to the project's classpath and put the `jmf.properties` file in the `src` directory. The method is:

```
Vector devices = CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList(  
if (devices == null) {
  System.out.println("Devices list is null");
  System.exit(0);
}
if (devices.size() == 0) {
  System.out.println("No devices found");
  System.exit(0);
}
```

It works on command line but it doens't work on Eclipse.

Comment: You've pasted a huge wall of code. Can you trim it down to the relevant parts only? This will help others troubleshoot the code easier; rather than having to go through your whole block of code and attempting to understand it.

Comment: It works on command line but it doesn't work on eclipse.